# Does ArcGIS API support Geoserver's WMS and WFS services?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, wfs

I want to know whether ArcGIS API for Java Script support Geoserver's WMS and WFS standards. I have published my data on Geoserver and i want to query my data by WFS in ArcGIS API to develope my appliction.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using. Afaik, ArcGIS 9 doesn't support WFS.

Comment: I have tried several WMS published with GeoServer in ArcGIS API for Flex and I was not able to use them. The only WMS that was working with ArcGIS API was from ArcGIS Server. I know that this is not answer to the question, but the situation with ArcGIS API for JavaScript may be similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are samples on using WMS:

- [WMS Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/layers_wms.html)
- [WMS Layer - Resource Info](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/layers_wmsresourceinfo.html)

I don't know of any examples using WFS so you would be on your own there.

Comment: I believe both of these examples use ArcGIS Online as data sources. The OP is asking about the use of a GeoServer wms and/or wfs with the ArcGIS API for Javascript. I looked into this briefly a while back, and I do not believe it works. I'd like to get verification from someone who knows for sure, though.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS API for Java Script. and i published my data on Geoserver. Now i want to confirm whether Geoserver's WFS and WMS standards can be imported to ArcGIS API for Java script ? Because ArcGIS API supports REST.

Comment: The examples use WMS (it doesn't matter where the layer comes from) so they do answer this question.